# remove animation from Nav buttons javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

this is website on which I am working
http://liveatdevonwood.com/floor-plans/

When I click on any of the image ,the image appears in lightbox
when I mouse-over the image, left-right navigation comes with it .. and disappears on mouse out.
can we make it static.. like when the lightbox is opened the nav buttons should appear right after that...?
these are the codes

http://liveatdevonwood.com/wp-content/plugins/lightbox-2/lightbox-print.js
http://liveatdevonwood.com/wp-content/plugins/lightbox-2/lightbox-resize.js

I have gone through css ,but no luck , Please help.

Comment: You should consult the plugin author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make few change in you css like,

Remove the `:hover` and `:visited:hover` from the below properties in `lightbox.css`

```
/** lightbox.css line 53 */
#stimuli_prevLink {
    background: url("images/prev.gif") no-repeat scroll left 55% rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

/** lightbox.css line 54 */
#stimuli_nextLink {
    background: url("images/next.gif") no-repeat scroll right 55% rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```